# How to access a hook setter in an onClick function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm rewriting a class component to a functional component, but i can't figure out how to access a hook setter in an onClick function.

I declare the hook as usual, which is a variable and a setter for accessing a username :

```
export function Header(props: IHeaderProps) {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');


    // set username in header if found in storage
    useEffect(() => {
        const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME) || '{}');

        if(token.Username) {
        setUsername(token.Username);
        }
    });......
```

In the JSX i have a "Sign out" button. When clicked, it invokes the handleLogout function, where i need to set the username to empty string:

```
    ....
    <span className="ms-Grid-col ms-u-sm4"><DefaultButton onClick={handleLogout} text="Log out" /></span>
    ....

function handleLogout() {
    ...
    // how can i set the username to empty string here?
}
```

But how can i achieve this? When this was a class component i had access to the state variable, what is the proper way to deal with this using hooks? I'm using typescript with the "cannot use lambda in the markup" rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the function inside the functional component and then access the component state.

```js
export function Header(props: IHeaderProps) {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

    function handleLogout() {
        // handle logout logic here
        setUsername('');
    }

    // set username in header if found in storage
    useEffect(() => {
        const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME) || '{}');

        if(token.Username) {
        setUsername(token.Username);
        }
    });......
```

Comment: This will not work though.? Effect function is triggered in every render because of no dependencies so if you trigger setUsername from logout, then react rerenders and in rerender call effect function which sets username from localStorage again.